# valgrind complains about uninitialized bytes on C++ structure

Tags: c++, initialization, valgrind

I have distilled by question down to a very simple example where I have a structure constructor that is initializing everything, yet valgrind complains about uninitialized bytes. The culprit seems to be the boolean member of the class, which causes padding bytes to be inserted before the size_t member. What is the right way to initialize those padding bytes so that valgrind doesn't complain?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define MAX 128

typedef struct foo_struct
{
  foo_struct(const std::string& name, bool q = true) : q(q)
  {
    if (name.size() > MAX)
    {
      throw std::runtime_error("too big");
    }
    point_name_size = name.size();
    memset(n, 0, sizeof(n));
    memcpy(n, name.c_str(), name.size());
  }

  bool q;
  size_t point_name_size;
  char n[MAX];
} foo_t;

int main()
{
  int fd = open("/tmp/foo", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
  if (-1 == fd)
  {
    throw std::runtime_error("Can't create File Descriptor: " + std::string(strerror(errno)));
  }

  const foo_t f("hello");
  ssize_t written = write(fd, &f, sizeof(f));
  std::cout << "wrote " << written << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compile and run with

```sh
g++ try.cpp && valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20  ./a.out
```

The valgrind error is

```
==11790== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==11790==    at 0x54ED154: write (write.c:27)
==11790==    by 0x1093DE: main (in /home/gri6507/tmp/a.out)
==11790==  Address 0x1fff000251 is on thread 1's stack
==11790==  in frame #1, created by main (???:)
```

Comment: please don't use typedef in c++. also the _t suffix is reserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to serialize a data structure into a chunk of bytes to be written to mass storage is to write a serializer that encodes the data into the desired format. Relying on things not specified by the standard (such as the endianness or type sizes) is simply wrong.

There are plenty of serialization libraries available.

Comment: I agree that this is the correct way. However, the expense of serialization and deserialization was too much in my real application, where the data was not actually written to a file, but rather communicated via a pipe between threads. So, my solution was to change the struct to a `union { struct {} unpacked; void * packed }`. This way, I could initialize the `packed` pointer during union constructor, memset to zero based on `sizeof(unpacked)` and my serializer was the `packed` pointer :-)

Comment: @PaulGrinberg Why would you communicate with a pipe between threads when threads share all memory?

Comment: I know that threads share memory. I needed to pass data to and trigger an event in a libev event loop. One of the easiest ways to do that was to use a pipe with a libev async event doing nonblocking select on the file handle.

Comment: @PaulGrinberg That's exactly what mutexes and condition variables are for.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the right way to initialize those padding bytes so that valgrind doesn't complain?

I'm not sure about 'the right way' to do this, but there are several possibilities.

1. you create members for the padding and initialize them

```
struct bar
{
  size_t point_name_size;
  char n[MAX];
  bool q;
  bool unused[7] ={};
};
```

This 'typically' has the same size as your struct on a 64 bit system. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c2bcf9d3d2a8ca3).

2. you fill yourself with 0's if you are trivially copyable

```
struct bar
{
  bar()
  {
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<bar>);
    memset(this, 0, sizeof(bar));      
  }

  size_t point_name_size;
  char n[MAX];
  bool q;
};
```